# Trying to create Teams Online Meeting through Graph API while adding attendees but i get an error [message] => Request payload cannot be null

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an online meeting after obtaining the user token. When I do not add any attendees to the meeting, it is generated successfully. However, if I add attendees to the meeting, the creation fails, and I receive a JSON response indicating the error. How can I correctly add attendees?

My code for generating the meeting:

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}

$accessToken = $_SESSION['access_token'];

function createTeamsMeeting($accessToken) {
    $attendees = [
        [
            'emailAddress' => [
                'address' => 'myemail@mydomain.com',
                'name' => 'its me'
            ],
            'type' => 'required'
        ]
        
    ];

    $graphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings";
    $meetingDetails = json_encode([
        'startDateTime' => '2023-12-01T11:00:00.0000000Z',
        'endDateTime' => '2023-12-01T12:00:00.0000000Z',
        'subject' => 'Example Teams Meeting',
        'attendees' => $attendees
    ]);

    $curl = curl_init($graphUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $meetingDetails);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($error) {
        return ['error' => $error];
    }

    return json_decode($response, true);
}

$meetingResponse = createTeamsMeeting($accessToken);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($meetingResponse);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

And the error I get:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => General
            [message] => Request payload cannot be null.
            [innerError] => Array
                (
                    [request-id] => ce248538-83da-42bd-a65c-6b67343c3fa0
                    [date] => 2023-11-13T12:57:28
                    [client-request-id] => ce248538-83da-42bd-a65c-6b67343c3fa0
                )

        )

)
```

I tried to format the ateeneds as shown in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting)

I get the same error